# Jquery mobile pages not executing JS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have a custom js file that I wrote, called Utility.js. When I load the page on the pc version (Index.cshtml), it works just fine. However, when I load Index.Mobile.cshtml, it doesn't execute. No idea what is going on. The Index.cshtml and Index.Mobile.cshtml pages are exactly the same.

_Layout.Mobile.cshtml:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/Mobile/css", "~/Content/jquerymobile/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jquerymobile")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/mobileCss", "~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/page_load.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/csspopup.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js")
</meta>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model m.lmcu.org.ViewModel.Model
@{
Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.Mobile.cshtml";
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"      type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Utility.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <code>
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you navigating directly to the mobile page or clicking a link? Because by default when you navigate to a page in JQM it only loads the body/first JQM page.

Comment: Its using a link, @Html.ActionLink(.....). It then hits the Controller ActionResult. I did manually put in the view to run: Return View("Index.Mobile"). I did this on the pc, so I could see if it was executing the javascript. Also another note, I put in js directly in the file and it still didn't work.

Comment: What about if your link has the `data-ajax="false"` attribute set? By [default](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/navigation-linking-pages/) JQM loads pages via ajax and only loads the first JQM page it finds (so you can also try including your script's within that JQM page).

Comment: I found the issue. My _layout.Mobile was missing the jquery-1.8.2.min.js reference.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem, since it turned out that it was just a missing file I'm going to vote to close the question.